# Cups does not honour Preview annotations & page rotations when creating a postscript file

Tags: pdf, postscript, cups

I have a pdf file that has been created by Adobe Indesign.

After this I open this file in Preview and rotate some pages highlight some tet and add an annotation (a speech bubble) and saved it again. File: http://public.pixelhobby.com.s3.amazonaws.com/indesign-portrait-example.pdf

I want to create a postscript file, with the following command

```
 cupsfilter -i "application/pdf" -m "application/vnd.cups-postscript" -f /Volumes/TEMPORARY/test-files/booklet_A4doc_A3-plus_paper_A4booklet/pdf/indesign-portrait-example.pdf > indesign-portrait-example.ps
```

The result is file: http://public.pixelhobby.com.s3.amazonaws.com/indesign-portrait-example.ps

As you can see, the page rotations, highlights and annotations are not honoured when creating a postscript file.

I think this issue is the cause of my problem when I'm trying to use the TwoUp feature (for a booklet) of my EFI Fiery driver of my Canon IPC-650 printer, and the page rotation and annotations are not printed in the booklet. When I do a normal print job, the rotations and annotations are visible and honoured.

I presume the cups postscript filter is used when printing, but only in those cases where a pages need to be newly imposed, but I'm not sure how this actually works.

This is not a `Preview` issue, I tried other tools to rotate the pages and still the same problem occured. The rotation flag can easily be discovered when using the following command:

```
pdfinfo -l 8 indesign-portrait-example.pdf
```

you will get:

```
Creator:        Adobe InDesign 15.0 (Macintosh)
Producer:       Adobe PDF Library 15.0
CreationDate:   Tue Oct 13 13:21:36 2020
ModDate:        Tue Oct 13 13:21:36 2020
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          8
Encrypted:      no
Page    1 size: 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
Page    2 size: 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4) (rotated 180 degrees)
Page    3 size: 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
Page    4 size: 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4) (rotated 180 degrees)
Page    5 size: 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
Page    6 size: 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4) (rotated 180 degrees)
Page    7 size: 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4) (rotated 0 degrees)
Page    8 size: 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4) (rotated 180 degrees)
File size:      377890 bytes
Optimized:      yes
PDF version:    1.5
```

How to create a postscript file that honours the rotation and annotations made in the pdf?